# Why assigning to Z does not work with PDAL

Tags: point, pdal, copc

I'm converting a CSV file to a LAZ(copc) format. My third column represent Z, but is called band_1. This shouldn't be a problem. Now I want to assign that to Z of the LAZ. But for some reason when I run my pipeline, I only get the message: "PDAL: filters.assign:"
Assigning the band_1 value to X it works perfectly fine.

This is my current pipeline:

```
[

  {        
    "type":"readers.text",
    "filename":"outputfile.csv",
    "header":"X, Y, band_1",
    "skip":1
  },
  {
    "type":"filters.range",
    "limits":"band_1[-1000:]"
  },
    {
    "type": "filters.assign",
    "value": "X = band_1"
  },
  {
    "type": "writers.copc",
    "filename": "Tif-Copc.copc.laz"
  }
]
```

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if am interpreting the [Documentation's example](https://pdal.io/en/2.6.0/stages/readers.text.html#example-2) incorrectly, but it seems  the `"header"` option can be used to overwrite the column names from the textfile. So instead of `"header":"X, Y, band_1"`, you can use `"header":"X, Y, Z"`.
If this works, you can also remove the `filters.assign` function.

My suggestion:

```json
[

  {        
    "type":"readers.text",
    "filename":"outputfile.csv",
    "header":"X, Y, Z",
    "skip":1
  },
  {
    "type":"filters.range",
    "limits":"Z[-1000:]"
  },
  {
    "type": "writers.copc",
    "filename": "Tif-Copc.copc.laz"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, That indeed worked! Totally forgot about my question. Thanks for your help. The column is just kinda of an index where I can assign my own 'indicator' to.